# Timestamp filter in PLSQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

Let's say I have an table containing a user rating of movies like IMDB movie database.

| ID | USER_REVIEW | USER_RATING | USER_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | blub | 10 | 1 |
| 2 | blob | 9 | 2 |
| 3 | blab | 7 | 3 |

These table inserts have been taken yesterday.
The entries with the id 1 and 2 have been taken between 16:00 and 16:10. The third entry with id 3 have been taken between 16:10 and 16:15 How can I find a select statement that filters me the first two entries between 16:00 and 16:10?
Or is it possible to find out which are the exact timestamps of the inserts from yesterday?

Answer (score 1):

> is it possible to find the exact timestamp of the inserts from yesterday?

Sure, if there's a timestamp column in the table.

---

As it looks as if such a column doesn't exist, a simple option to add it is

```
alter table movies add date_insert date default sysdate;
```

Oracle will auto-populate that column with `SYSDATE` (unless you explicitly insert it), which means that your current `INSERT` statement remains "as is", you don't have to change it a bit.

Then you'd - for example - select rows inserted *yesterday* as

```
select *
from movies
where trunc(date_insert) = trunc(sysdate - 1)
```

Or, as you asked, rows inserted yesterday (10th of August 2021) between 16:00 and 16:10:

```
select * 
from movies
where date_insert between to_date('10.08.2021 16:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi')
                      and to_date('10.08.2021 16:10', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi')
```

Comment: But if I use select * from (table_name) where trunc(date_insert) = trunc(sysdate - 1), the insert is not working and nothing change. The new column "date_insert" remains to sysdate

Comment: Of course. Did you read what I said? Why do you think that SELECT will modify table's contents? It never does. It is **INSERT** which will do that. So: if you currently don't have such a timestamp column, you can't retrieve data you're interested in. You *could* add a new column (as I demonstrated) and update rows currently stored in the table, but that's purely manual job and you have to know when you inserted those previous rows. DEFAULT column value will take effect & be meaningful for **newly added rows**.

Answer (score -1):

try the GETDATE() function.
here is something to help you:
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1145/date-and-time-conversions-using-sql-server/

Comment: The GETDATE() function only works for sql server. I am using oracle sql so SYSDATE works